# Pip could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)

Tags: pip, pytorch

I am trying to install PyTorch on my Windows 11. I have Python 3.8.1, and pip 22.2.2. I have tried running the command `py -m pip install torch`, but it keeps returning the error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch
```

I have gone through various StackOverflow posts and tried many different strategies. I even uninstalled and re-installed pip on my system using the get-pip.py file. Nothing seems to work.

Suggestions?

Comment: I think you would need to provide details for anyone to be able to help you. You said you tried other Q&As; then it would be wise to edit your answers and expand on how your case is different than the ones in these other Q&As.

Answer (score 5):

Just came across another post that mentioned how it needs to be the 64-bit version of Python to allow installation of PyTorch.
Just installed Python 3.9.13 with the 64-bit installer, and the installation worked. So, if anyone else is running into issues, would recommend first running `python` in command shell and checking whether it is 64 bit or 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the issue while installing PyTorch in Mac

Followed these steps to get it resolved

**Step 1**

Check the platform version and python version

Needs to be 64 bit

*Reference*

*[https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/windows.html#:~:text=PyTorch%20doesn't%20work%20on,and%20Python%2064%2Dbit%20version.](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/windows.html#:%7E:text=PyTorch%20doesn%27t%20work%20on,and%20Python%2064%2Dbit%20version.)*

**Step1.1**

Check if Python is 64 bit

Should return True for 64 bit

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.maxsize > 2**32)"
```

**Step1.2**

Check if Processor is 64 bit in Mac

Used Python script to do the check

```
import platform
print('Platform processor:', platform.processor())
print('Platform architecture:',platform.architecture())
```

Should get a result similar to

Platform processor: i386

Platform architecture: ('64bit', '')

**Step 2**

Check if the pip version is uptodate and upgrade to latest version using

python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

**Step 3**

Reinstalled Pytorch

```
pip3 install torch torchvision
```